# count from another table with inner

Tags: mysql

i want to get the number of occures in another Table in MySQL.

My current Query looks like following:

```
SELECT
teilnehmer.`name`,
teilnehmer.`status`
FROM
teilnehmer
INNER JOIN chat ON chat.cid = teilnehmer.id
INNER JOIN videos ON videos.tid = teilnehmer.id
GROUP BY
chat.id,
videos.tid
```

I want now the amount of teilnehmer.id's in chat.cid's and the amount of teilehmer.id's in videos.tid's

How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: Some clarification of your relational model would help. Looks like you should be modeling a many-to-many relationship instead.

Comment: I have a MySQL Designer for such things. maybe a screenshot will help you. I have added the Picture at the question...

Comment: can you make it ins sqlfiddle an example of your tables?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want this:

```
SELECT teilnehmer.`name`,
  teilnehmer.`status`,
  c.ChatCount,
  v.VideoCount
FROM teilnehmer
INNER JOIN
(
  select count(cid) ChatCount, cid
  from chat 
  group by cid
) c
  ON c.cid = teilnehmer.id
INNER JOIN
(
  select count(tid) VideoCount, tid
  from videos 
  group by tid
) v
  ON v.tid = teilnehmer.id
```

Comment: +1 even though I'd format the query quite differently; it would be using the same technique.